# regex find lines with two sets of duplicates

Tags: regex

using regex is it possible to only find lines with two sets up duplicates such as

```
agaig (two a/g)
aagia (ignore this line)
aaigg (two a/g)
```

using the current regex

```
/(.){2}(?=.*?\1)
```

it highlights the 'aagia' and I don't want that line only lines with two sets of duplicates

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(?=.*(.).*?\1)(?=.*(?!\1)(.).*?\2).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7fF7c5/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*(.).*?\1)` - there must be (not necessarily consecutive) two repeated chars in the string (`(.)` captures a single char into Group 1)
- `(?=.*(?!\1)(.).*?\2)` - there must be (not necessarily consecutive) two repeated chars in the string that are not identical to the char captured in Group 1
- `.*` - the rest of the line.